Horizons for observers falling into a black hole?
The past light cone of an observer falling into a black hole does not contain the entire external spacetime. So the infalling observer becomes cut off from receiving information from (parts of?) the external spacetime.
My main question is: Can this "cutting off" be modelled as the appearance of an horizon for the observer, like an event horizon or similar, behind which they cannot see?
Possible follow-ups if yes:

Would such a horizon emit Hawking radiation?
Does this horizon shrink to a size of zero as the observer approaches the singularity?
And now really speculatively, if yes, would the infalling observer thus experience a kind of miniature "Big Rip"-scenario comparable to
the cosmological case, where the cosmological event horizon shrinks
to zero?

EDIT: To make it a bit more precise, compare with an observer in Minkowski space: The union of the observer's past light cones along the worldline will cover the entire spacetime in many cases, won't it? I guess not if the observer is permenantly accelerated, in which case their Rindler horizon will prevent them from seeing a part of the spacetime. But you can see that in this example the inaccessibility of a part of the spacetime is associated with the appearance of a horizon. My main question above is basically if this is the same for the observer falling into a black hole.

The past light cone of any observer never contains the entire spacetime, so it's not clear what do you mean by that

@J.Delaney Maybe I formulated that a bit imprecisely. Compare with an observer in Minkowski space: The union of the observer's past light cones will cover the entire spacetime in many cases, won't it? I guess not if the observer is permenantly accelerated, in which case their Rindler horizon will prevent them from seeing a part of the spacetime. But you can see that in this example the inaccesibility of a part of the spacetime is associated with the appearance of a horizon. My main question above is basically if this is the same for the observer falling into a black hole.

The past light cone of a falling observer is hardly any different from anyone else's until they get very close to the EH, and then only for the brief time until they meet the singularity.

Wouldn't it be a stationary observer near a black hole that might be equivalent to a Rindler observer? A free falling observer is inertial.

@ProfRob Yes, the infalling observer is in free fall, so they would not have a standard Rindler horizon like an accelerated observer in Minkoswki space. Still, the infalling observer seems to be cut off from large parts of the external spacetime, so my question is whether we can associated this with the appearance of some kind of horizon, even if it is not a Rindler horizon.

Are you looking for the cosmic event horizon?

@PSR "The union of the observer's past light cones along the worldline will cover the entire spacetime in many cases, won't it?" No. The past light cone at time $t$ is contained in the past light cone of time $t' > t$, so their union is just the past light cone in the current point in time.

@J.Delaney Well for any finite t' you can do it like this, but if you want to consider the entire worldline including possibly t' -> infinity, the past light cone at any finite t' will not be identical to the union of all past light cones along the worldline.

@paulina No, I think not quite, though I guess the more speculative parts of my question somewhat aim to see whether a connection like this can be made.

“observer becomes cut off from receiving information from (parts of?) the external spacetime” - Everything that ever crosses the event horizon does so at the same time. At this moment the external universe ceases to exist in the world of a falling observer. He still can see the light apparently from behind, but this light already is inside the event horizon just spatially separated along the Schwarzschild $t$ coordinate. You are correct that he doesn’t see all of this light, but this new “horizon” is inside the event horizon: https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/talks/insidebh/schwJoopath.html

@PSR The past light cone of an observer at any given point is the set of all spacetime points connected to that point by a timelike path, therefore it is  by definition identical to the union of all past light cones along the worldline.
